# Potential of spherically symmetric charge distribution

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, gauss-law

For a spherically symmetric charge distribution that extends to infinity, I am interested in finding the potential $V(r)$.

I know that the formula is $V=-\int \vec{E} \cdot \overrightarrow{d l}$ and the electric field can be found by forming a spherical surface and applying Gauss's law, but I am unsure of how to conceptualize the limits of integration. For a localized source, say, a point charge, one would integrate from infinity to $r$. But for a charge distribution (that decays over distance), can one apply the same limits?

Note that I am interested in a distribution that, although infinite in extent, does have a convergent total charge if integrating the charge density over all space.

Comment: Is there any alternative to using the same limits?

Comment: You choose the reference point and limits that match your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are conflating two different concepts: the potential $V(r)$ and the potential *difference* (i.e. the voltage) $\Delta V$, which is linked to but it's not the same thing as $V(r)$. In fact, while $V(r)$ is a function, $\Delta V$ is defined as the difference between the values that $V(r)$ takes in two points.

For a point charge $q$, the voltage between points A and B (which are at distance $r_A$ and $r_B$ from $q$, respectively) is given by

$$
\Delta V_{AB} = - \int_A^B \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{l} = \frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \left(\frac{1}{r_B} - \frac{1}{r_A} \right) \equiv V(B) - V(A),
$$

from which we can infer the form of the potential function:

$$
V(r) = \frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon_0r} + C,
$$

where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. It is thus evident that there is an entire (*infinite*) set of potential functions that result in the same voltage.

If now consider a continuous charge distribution, you go from $q$ to $dq$ and from $V(r)$ to $dV(r)$, so that the final potential in the generic point P will be given by

$$
V(P) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int_Q \frac{dq}{r} + C
$$

where the integral runs over all the charge, and the $r$ inside the integral is the distance between $dq$ and point $P$. If you are dealing with a spherically symmetric charge distribution, $dq = 4 \pi r^2 \rho(r) dr$ and hence we obtain

$$
V(P) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int_0^\infty 4 \pi r \rho(r) dr + C = \frac{1}{ \epsilon_0} \int_0^\infty r \rho(r) dr + C
$$

If you now want to compute the voltage between two points, this is just

$$
\Delta V_{PQ} = V(Q) - V(P)
$$

Comment: In physical situations, you always have limits, and you do not need a constant, C.

Comment: Unless your charge distribution is infinite, as OP has stated

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is valid if you already know $\mathbf{E}$. The actual formula to convert a constant charge density $\rho$ to an electric field is this:

$$\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0 }\iiint_{R^3}\frac{\rho(\mathbf{r'})(\mathbf{r-r'})}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|^3 }dV'$$

Note that the usual formula for $V$ in terms of $\rho$ does not converge if your charge density extends to infinity:

$$V(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0 }\iiint_{R^3}\frac{\rho(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r-r'}| }dV'$$

Note that the domain of integration is always **all of space**. In cases where you integrate over a finite charge distribution (e.g. a sphere of radius $R$), you are actually integrating over all space but noting that $\rho$ is 0 everywhere outside of the sphere. So you may as well limit your domain to the sphere. The same is true for one dimensional charge distributions: technically, the charge distribution $\lambda$ is equal to a 3-D charge distribution times a dirac delta function in the remaining
two variables. You integrate over all of space which is equivalent to integrating on a domain at which $\rho$ is non-zero.

Once you use the equation above to find the electric field, you can use this equation to get the potential:

$$V(\mathbf{r})-V(\mathbf{r_0})=-\int_C\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r'})\cdot d \mathbf{l'}$$

where $C$ is a path from $\mathbf{r_0}$ to $\mathbf{r}$. The fun thing is that this path literally doesn't matter, because the electrostatic field is curl-less and conservative! This means that you will get the same answer no matter which path you take. Typically, in spherical coordinates, I choose a path with three segments in which only one variable changes at a time, but you can literally choose any path. If your distribution is spherically symmetric, then you normally don't have to worry about $\phi'$ or $\theta'$ and just do the line integral over $r'$.